# Fetching qgis plugins on 2.12.0 Lyon is taking a very long time

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins

Opening plugins for the first time on QGIS 2.12.0 Lyon there is a window popping up saying "fetching repositories". You can't do anything until it's finished. It then takes it ages to fetch. Any solutions? (I'm using windows 7)

Comment: Perhaps your computer is behind a proxy or firewall which prevents QGIS from accessing the plugins?